# Flutter, what happen if there are memory leaks?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I know memory leaks are bad, and of course it's good to optimize to save memory.

But what if the memory leak continues and overflows with nests? Will the app force quit?

Let's say you have 10000 Stream Controllers open and don't cancel continuously.

What happens? This is a huge memory leak.

If the app is forcibly shut down, how much memory must leak before the app shuts down? What are the limits? How do I check the amount of leaks everytime?